# Provoking MySQL read/write timeouts

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to test query timeouts systematically using a MySQL 5.6 server without overloading the server by some insane busy query? Is it maybe possible to build testing SQL statements (read and/or write) that run infinitely (or several minutes) without driving the server into the ground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a [sleep() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep), so you can do this:

```
SELECT SLEEP(10);
```

to craft a query that will take 10 seconds without taking up resources. Sleep returns either 0 or 1 so you can take advantage of that to craft an update or delete query that will have no effect:

```
UPDATE users SET username='blah' WHERE id=1 AND SLEEP(1) > 1;
```

you need to ensure that the rest of the where clause (id=1 in this case) matches exactly one row. If it matches more than one row, it will sleep for every single row it matches, if it matches zero, it will return immediately.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Is there also a way to use SLEEP in a writing query?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. I edited my answer to show how you could use it in an update query.